# How do I change the year if I want to use the same spread sheet we used last year?

Tags: google-sheets

We have a spreadsheet we use every day.  One for each month.    In creating new ones for 2019,  I can not get the date to stay correct.  For instance it says Mon Jan 1    which is 2018,   When I type it to Tue Jan 1  for 2019  it automatically changes back to Monday  like in 2018.  How do I change the automatic year setting?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

Type your date with the year 2019 included. If you don’t, google sheets think you trying to type a date on the current year.